# Windows 10 - Network Drive (WebDAV) access limited

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, network-drive, webdav

I've connected MS Windows through the explorer (File Manager) with a WebDAV server. Everything seems to work correct, I can download files and create directories. But if I try to upload files to the server through the mounted network drive, I got the message that the file already exists.

I'm **definetly sure** that the file doesn't exist! However I tried to *"overwrite"* the allegedly existing file but it also doesn't work! If I tried to overwrite it, Windows cancels the action with the following message:

> Die Quelldatei oder vom Quelldatenträger kann nicht gelesen werden.

English: *Can't read from source file or disk*

Moreover I can edit already existing files and save changes for some file types like *.java files for example. My IDE IntelliJ sends a warning but seems to support updating the file. **But I still can't upload files!**

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: Is "Require Lock for Writing" set in WebDAV Settings under Lock Behavior? If set, does setting it to False changes anything?

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure if I understand you write which WebDAV settings do you mean? I connected with the WebDAV server through the windoss file explorer I didn't find any WebDAV specific settings?

Comment: It's done on the server side.

Comment: @harrymc Okay that doesn't solve my issue... The owner of the WebDAV server is the university so I doesn't have any control about it

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the university's WebDAV administrator and ask him how to do it in an authorized manner.